# Misaligned label "Stack Apps Post (optional)" on app information page

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, apps, design

When editing the application information (from https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/), the label for the optional Stack Apps Post is misaligned:

[image]

It should be left-aligned like the other labels; the only difference I can spot is that the `input` element below it is not wrapped in a `div`, like the others are.

Comment: Related post "[stackapps register page: “Enable Client Side OAuth Flow” position](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273287/312043)" in MSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed with the new Stacks design:

[image]